# 'iterator' file not found when compiling bar for iOS

Tags: clang, c11

I was using Xcode 11 to compile zbar for my iOS Device.
However it gives me this error:`'iterator' file not found`

Some code:

```cpp
#ifndef _ZBAR_IMAGE_H_
#define _ZBAR_IMAGE_H_

/// @file
/// Image C++ wrapper

#ifndef _ZBAR_H_
# error "include zbar.h in your application, **not** zbar/Image.h"
#endif

#include <assert.h>
#include <iterator>
#include "Symbol.h"
#include "Exception.h"
```

I have tried to clean and rebuild and this didn't seem to work.

Environment:
Mac OS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A558d)
Xcode 11.0(11A420a)
C11

Comment: what is file extension, `*.c` or `*.cpp` ?

Comment: the file extension is ``*.h``

Comment: and which one is including this header file? or complied with `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: It's a Xcode project, image.c is calling it.

Answer (score 0):

`<iterator>` is a c++ reference, please refer to [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/).

so,

> a. Renaming the `image.c` to `image.cpp`

or

> b. Compile with `g++`, NOT `gcc`

would be helpful.

Comment: Changing to C++ compiler create even more errors. Most of them were unknown types

Comment: I delete the zbar and finally the lib compiled. Thanks anyway!